# Access 2D Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have created a **2D Array** and trying to access each elements but i am receiving wrong value of each array .I can see only **Today** as the value

```
<?php

$blog = array ( 
        0 => array('by' => "Nilay Mehta", 'on' => "Today", 'id' => "Today", 'post' => "Today"),
        1 => array('by' => "Nilay Mehta", 'on' => "Today", 'id' => "Today", 'post' => "Today"),
        2 => array('by' => "Nilay Mehta", 'on' => "Today", 'id' => "Today", 'post' => "Today"),
        3 => array('by' => "Nilay Mehta", 'on' => "Today", 'id' => "Today", 'post' => "Today"),
);

foreach($blog as $blog)
{
    echo "<a href=\"#\">".$blog['by']."</a>";
    echo "<div class=\"blogtime\"> - ".$blog['on']."</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"blogtime\">Blog Post ID - ".$blog['id'];
    echo $blog['post'];
}
?>
```

Comment: foreach($blog as $blog) !!!!!!

Comment: @MohamadMehdiHabibi - you mean he needs to use `foreach($blogs as $blog)` or `foreach ($blog as $b)`..

Comment: yes @Obmerk Kronen. for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this `as $blog` will overwrite the original `$blog` variable and for the first time you can access the value but then it will not work as expected. change the second `$blog` to anything else as I did

```
foreach($blog as $b)
{
    echo "<a href=\"#\">".$b['by']."</a>";
    echo "<div class=\"blogtime\"> - ".$b['on']."</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"blogtime\">Blog Post ID - ".$b['id'];
    echo $b['post'];
}
```

in your case the `$blog` will become from

```
array ( 
        0 => array('by' => "Nilay Mehta", 'on' => "Today", 'id' => "Today", 'post' => "Today"),
        1 => array('by' => "Nilay Mehta", 'on' => "Today", 'id' => "Today", 'post' => "Today"),
        2 => array('by' => "Nilay Mehta", 'on' => "Today", 'id' => "Today", 'post' => "Today"),
        3 => array('by' => "Nilay Mehta", 'on' => "Today", 'id' => "Today", 'post' => "Today"),
);
```

to

```
array('by' => "Nilay Mehta", 'on' => "Today", 'id' => "Today", 'post' => "Today");
```

Comment: +1 .. Or for clarity use `$blogs = array()` and then `foreach ($blogs as $blog)`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `foreach($blog as $ind_blog)` instead of `foreach($blog as $blog)`, in current system `$blog` array replaced by the first occurance of the loop with same variable..